# using ssh.net im not able to getting output

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

I'm not getting any output after running script. Please someone help me why the output is showing empty.

I can see its connecting to server.

```cs
namespace WebApplication10.helpers
{
    public class service
    {
        public static List<Servicestatus> serviceadd(servername,UserName,Password)
        {
            List<Servicestatus> results = new List<Servicestatus>();
            try
            {
                using (var client = new SshClient(servername, UserName, Password))
                {
                    client.Connect();

                    SshCommand strOutput = client.CreateCommand("service --status-all");
                    var str = strOutput.Execute();

                    Console.WriteLine(str)

                    client.Disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( e.Message );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of application is this? A console application? A form application?

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the response with `yourCommand.Result`

```
SshCommand command = client.CreateCommand("service --status-all");
command.Execute();
Console.WriteLine(command.Result)
```

Comment: im getting this error bash: service: command not found

Comment: There you have your output. The command tried to run but was unsuccessful. According to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800155/service-command-not-found) command not found typically results from 2 cases: 1. An executable not having execute permissions for your user or group. 2. An executable not belonging to a folder listed in `PATH` variable , or the opposite - `PATH` variable that does not contain the location of your executable.